# How to allow a backbone function to execute before rendering the view using coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, drop-down-menu, coffeescript, race-condition

I have a Rails application that uses backbone and coffeescript to make the interface nicer.  However, I am running into some problems.  I suspect the problem is a race condition.  It is best to further clarify using a code snippet.

Here is a snippet of my coffeescript code:

```
class VGStream.Views.Scenarios.TypeWellScheduleForm extends VGStream.Views.Base.AjaxForm
  className: 'schedule-form'
  template: JST['backbone/templates/scenarios/type_well_schedule_form']

  initialize: (options) ->
    super
    @typeWells = options.typeWells

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template @
    @$('.well_type').val @model.get('scheduleable_type')
    @setWellSelection()
    @$('.well_id').val @model.get('scheduleable_id')
    @$('.exclude').val if @model.get 'exclude' then 1 else 0
    @calculateNetAcreage()
    @

  setWellSelection: ->
    if @$('.well_type').val() == 'TypeWell'
      wells = @typeWells.computed
    else
      wells = @typeWells.imported

    wellSelect = @$('.well_id')

    wellSelect.empty()

    for well in wells.models
      wellOption =  $ '<option>',
        value: well.get 'id'
        text:  well.get 'name'
      wellSelect.append wellOption
```

The setWellSelection function populates a drop-down select box's options as you can see from the function definition.  It has close to 1000 options.  I agree that I should not allow as many options in a drop-down select, but that is a battle I want to fight later.

This code works perfectly on my local machine since there is no network delay on the localhost.  The drop-down's options are displayed without any problems.  However, on the network, with the application deployed on Heroku, the dropdowns do not display until I fiddle around with clicking on the dropdown list, and then it displays.  Once loaded, then everything works correctly.

What I would like to do is to make the setWellSelection call synchronous somehow so that it has a chance to populate the dropdown select box before the rest of the render function executes and the template is displayed.

I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the html returned from your template before rendering it to the screen.

You could modify the html directly cause it's only string. This way you will have a nice performance solution but will be hard and painful to maintain.

Another way is to turn the html string to jquery object and modify it which I think is a better way, even though it may be slow. Later you can grab the updated html from jquery object and render to screen.

Comment: So I appreciate your response and time.  I have proved to myself by limiting the number of records returned so that the rendering of HTML is fast.  What I wanted to know is how to make the call to 'setWellSelection' function 'synchronous' instead of asynchronous which is the Javascript default.  That way, I get a realistic sense of how long it takes for not only 1000 records to come back from the server, but more importantly, how long then it takes to 'build' the HTML options.